# "Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings" on Facebook login at a test host

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook PHP SDK to implement login with facebook. And I want to test it in local first. I created a test app and I tried many things but still does not work for me.

In my local I have an apache virtual host configured so that I can access my local web app with this url: http://www.myapplocal.com

Here is the error that I get after signing in with facebook:

```
Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

And here is what I have in the oauth settings section:

```
Client OAuth Login: yes
Web OAuth Login: yes
Force Web OAuth Reauthentication: no
Embedded Browser OAuth Login: no
Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://www.myapplocal.com/index.php/facebook-login-callback
Login from Devices: no
```

And here is what I have in the section "Basic" (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/appid/settings/basic/):

```
Namespace:
App domains: www.myapplocal.com
Site Url: http://www.myapplocal.com/
```

Comment: Good edits. I think you've done a much better job of describing a specific issue. I've voted to reopen, and I see that someone else has as well. As a sidenote, you should avoid adding things like "thanks" and other fluff. It doesn't add anything to your question, and you can show appreciation for others by upvoting good answers and accepting the one that best solves your issue.

Comment: @skrrgwasme thank you for your feedback and help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After implementing login with google and login with twitter, I did not think that login with facebook would handle URLs differently. The problem was that for facebook, if your site works with both www and without it (http://example.com, http://www.example.com), you have to enter both in the app settings (http://www.example.com/facebook-callback and http://example.com/facebook-callback)

Comment: What to do if development is on localhost ?

Comment: Set alias on your local PC (in linux/mac it is in /etc/hosts where you can specify, that www.abcd.xyz will go to your local machine and everytime when you go to this address, you will get to localhost..

Comment: And what if I put my address to app settings and I have validation error - Invalid IP address format ? http://prntscr.com/av0qfw

Answer (score 3):

also I found that http and https have to be entered in App in "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" if your site uses SSL certificate.

Comment: I wish I could give you a more up-votes for this. I was battling this for a while

Comment: @AbuSulaiman, Thank you. I am glad you and other people are finding this useful.

Comment: This is no longer applicable, as it requires HTTPS now.